# CS 1.6 server's request cartography

Tags: c#, client-server

Is there a way to request a CS 1.6, CS:Sourse or CS:GO servers to get the location coordinates of the recent deaths of players on the game map?

PS I'm using C# for my project

Comment: Doing a quick search on counterstrike data, I came across a [user who's done some analysis](https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/72m6h7/comment/dnjiyaz) and [talked about their process](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/72fkl7/mm_analytics_some_pistol_round_statistics_and/). Those threads may have some leads for you.

Answer (score -1):

I know you are using C# for the project, but amxmodx & sourcemod can be used to achieve this.  They are third party addons you can make plugins for.

Comment: That's cool! How would they get the location coordinates of the recent players death with amxmodx and sourcemod?